# Tenho uma classe Java onde um dos atributos é um ArrayList de outro objeto. Como trazer isso do banco de dados?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

Tenho um objeto java parecido com isso:

```
public class Objeto1 { 
    private int id;
    private int nome;
    private ArrayList<Objeto2> lista;

    //construtor e Getters e Setters
}
```

Como faço para conseguir trazer essa lista do banco de dados? É possível fazer na mesma query ou preciso usar uma query para o objeto principal e outra para preencher a lista?

Aqui usamos JDBC normal, não usamos nenhuma biblioteca JPA

Para pegar o Objeto do banco, usamos algo parecido com isso:

```
public Objeto1 selecionar(int identificador){
        Objeto1 obj1 = new Objeto1();

        try{
            if(conexao.isClosed()) abreConexao();
            PreparedStatement ps = conexao.prepareStatement("SP_BUSCA_OBJETO_1_IDTFD ?");
            ps.setInt(1, identificador);

            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

            while(rs.next()){
                obj1.setId = (rs.getInt("id")) ;
                obj1.setNome = (rs.getString("nome"));
            }
        } catch (Exception e){
            obj1 = null;
        } finally {
            fechaConexao();
        }

        return obj1;
    }
```

Como seria uma maneira mais limpa de pegar o atributo "lista" vindo do banco de dados?

Comment: Você quer saber como pegar a lista ou refatorar esse código pegando a lista ?

Comment: Eu queria saber o melhor jeito para pegar a lista. Se tem como fazer em uma só query, ou se eu teria que popular depois (Uma query para popular o Objeto1, outra query para popular a lista dentro de Objeto1)

Answer (score 0):

Faz um join entre as duas tabelas:

`Select obj1.id as id_obj1, obj1.nome, obj2.id as id_obj2, obj2.coluna_a, obj2.coluna_b FROM objeto1 obj1 JOIN objeto2 obj2 ON obj1.id = obj2.id_obj1`

Depois você percorre o result set e realiza o preenchimento da lista

```
public List<Objeto1> selecionar(int identificador){
    List<Objeto1> retorno =  new ArrayList<Objeto1>();
    try{
        if(conexao.isClosed()) abreConexao();
        PreparedStatement ps = conexao.prepareStatement("SP_BUSCA_OBJETO_1_IDTFD ?");
        ps.setInt(1, identificador);

        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

        while(rs.next()){
            Objeto1 obj1 = new Objeto1();
            obj1.setId = (rs.getInt("id_obj1")) ;
            if(retorno.contains(obj1)) {
              obj1 = retorno.get(retorno.indexOf(obj1));
              Objeto2 obj2 =  new Objeto2();
              obj2.setId(rs.getI("id_obj2));
              obj2.setColunaA(rs.getString("coluna_a)); 
              obj2.setColunaA(rs.getString("coluna_a));
              obj2.setObjeto1(obj1);

              obj1.getLista().add(obj2);
            }
            else {
              obj1.setLista(new ArrayList<Objeto2>());
              obj1.setNome = (rs.getString("nome"));
              Objeto2 obj2 =  new Objeto2();
              obj2.setId(rs.getI("id_obj2));
              obj2.setColunaA(rs.getString("coluna_a)); 
              obj2.setColunaA(rs.getString("coluna_a));
              obj2.setObjeto1(obj1);

              obj1.getLista().add(obj2);
              retorno.add(obj1);
            }

        }
    } catch (Exception e){
        retorno = null;
    } finally {
        fechaConexao();
    }


    return retorno;
}
```